# entity-like or the semantic difference between spark and pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Semantically, spark is a framework.

1)Pyspark is just a collection of python-like callers to functions written in scala?

if i m defining my own set of functions instead of standard functions like this:

```
def sum(a,b):
   return a+b

def subtract(a,b):
   return a-b
```

and using them instead of doing regular:

```
c = a+b
c = sum(a,b)
```

is this similar to the nature of pyspark inner working mechanism?
Pyspark is basically similar syntax for those who dont know Scala but want to start using spark right away ?

2)If i'm using python on spark - then I'm using pyspark.
Are the 2 statements correct in regard to pyspark?

Comment: Have you read through [PySpark Internals](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/PySpark+Internals)?

Comment: @ernest_k, honestly no, i thought i would get a laconic precise answer on stack overflow..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Pyspark is just a collection of python-like callers to functions written in scala?

Maybe this is what you mean... The underlying engine is the same. I suppose a better analogy could be *Pyspark is to "Spark" as httplib and okhttp are to http*. It gives you an API that invokes the same core engine. As Spark runs on the JVM, driver programs we write in JVM languages (like Scala or Java) use the API directly, but programs written against the Python API go through a Python interpreter running on the JVM. This is a matter of implementation, though.

Rather than another implementation of the same API in a different language, Pyspark is more like a different interface to the same implementation. Of course, the driver program itself brings the need to run Python code in the execution (Python functions/code invoked in the program).

> 2) If I'm using Python on spark - then I'm using Pyspark.

If you call the Python API for Spark, write your driver program in Python, then you're doing Pyspark. In this, I include calling the modules provided by Pyspark (such as `pyspark.sql.*`), and your own functions/logic called in your pipelines (such as `my_rdd.map(my_custom_function)`, where `my_custom_function` is your own function written in Python). *"Using Python on spark"* sounds to me like Spark is a Python implementation, which is not the case (or at least not meant to be).

---

Now, after all that, it's worth mentioning that *Pyspark* is part of *Spark* ecosystem. It's just that we have no popular names for *Spark with Scala* ("ScalaSpark"?) or *Spark with Java* as we have *Pyspark* and *SparkR*.

Comment: this "scala spark"  vs "py spark" is what bogged me! i was thinking of it "where is java spark?"

Comment: Probably a result of the fact that core spark is implemented in Scala. Even Java has a dedicated API on top of it (as far as I know). So scala uses the main thing, Java of course running on the JVM with the scala code got no special name, but language bindings for different platforms got names. But the implementation of the engine is the same.

Comment: still - sparkR , "spark with java" (instead of javaspark) , pyspark - all of them are just CONVENIENT(that's the keyword) ways to use spark without overhead of stumbling upon syntax.. - am i right? 
"core spark is implemented in scala" - because of this, right? not many people know scala, it's a narrow language. but many more know python..

Comment: anyways, - i should not spend too much time  on this scala vs python right? the diff is rather about convenience and whatever language is easier for me to write queries in, manipulate dataset  - am i right?

Comment: I think that's about right, although I wouldn't say it's about convenience. It's more like a Printer manufacturer making drivers available for Windows, Linux, etc. You can say it's about "convenience" for the Linux user in a sense (as they don't ask you to switch to Windows - where hypothetically the printer's workings were originally implemented). But I'd say it's about the platform's availability to other languages (this is just a different view point). Yes, the development language is a major adoption barrier: Many java developers won't use Pandas because they don't know Python (kinda).

Comment: thx Ernest, nice clarification.. the major point for interviews is to explain the rdd, how it works, clusters etc. pyspark itself is not that crucial as being able to explain the inner mechanism of spark framework.